# python dictionary--turn set of one-itemed list values into float value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have simply beginner python question. I have a dictionary that with values composed of one-itemed lists. How can I remove these items from the set of lists to get just a float?

```
dict = {key1: set([1]), key2: set([3]), key3:set([4])}
```

desired result:

```
resultdict = {key1: 1, key2: 3, key3: 4}
```

I had succeeded to remove the dictionary from a lists like so, but the set throws me off:

```
for k mydict:
    mydict[k] = mydict[k][0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also make each set a list and access by the index:

```
 {k:list(v)[0] for k,v in my_dict.iteritems()}
```

If you are  going to throw away the old dict you can use `.pop`

```
{k:v.pop() for k,v in my_dict.iteritems()}
```

I am not sure if you actually want floats or you meant ints in your question but if you want floats just cast as a float:

```
{k: float(v.pop()) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems()}
```

Comment: @mgilson, I suppose it would be the most efficient but would only work if the OP does not want to use the old dict elsewhere, your `iter` solution is the nicest overall.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
resultdict = {k: next(iter(s)) for k, s in input_dict.items()}
```

which works because `next(iter(s))` takes the "first" element in the set:

```
>>> s = set([1])
>>> next(iter(s))
1
```

Note that you wouldn't want to do this with sets that have multiple items -- You'd never know which element you'd get.

---

There are other ways too:

```
list(s)[0]
tuple(s)[0]
```

would work too, but I'm guessing they'd be less efficient (though you'd have to `timeit` to know).